# On the round half to even of the denormalized number to the smallest normal number in IEEE754

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

This is a very simple question but needs an expert to answer.

As we know, with subnormal in floating-point, we get rid off the gap between `2^emin` and `0`.

By the round half to even (RTE) mode, we should round the infinite precision result as `(0.1111...1|r)*2^emin` or `(1.1111...1|r')*2^(emin-1)`? The number on the left of the point is the implicit bit.

**For the first case:**
In the paper *What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic numerical computing*, in Figure2, I see the space on the left of `2^emin` is the same as the space on its right. So, straightforwardly, the numerical value of the left number is `2^emin - 2^(1-p)` (`p=24` in flp32). If we do RTE rounding, seems we should use the bit after 24bit significant as the rounding bit (i.e. `(0.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111|r)*2^emin`, see

```
--|---+---+....+-?-|---+---+....+---|-------+........
--0---------------2^emin---------2^emin+1
```

I use a question mark (`?`) on the axis to represent the half point

**For the second case:** In the IEEE standard, for subnormal detection, before rounding it says "unbounded" exponent blabla. So if we can have unbounded exponent, we can shift the exact result to `(1.1111...1|r')*2^(emin-1)`. Under this case, we have the half-sized left space on `2^emin`. This is similar to all other adjacent spaces on `2^e`, but once closing to 0 on the axis, the number of spaces is infinite. See

```
--|...++++|-+-+-+...|---+---+....+-?-|-------+........
--0-....----------2^emin-1----------2^emin
------| here is keep shrinking
```

In this case, seems we should round the exact result as

```
(1.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111|r')*2^(emin-1)
```

By 1-bit-left shifting the case 1 result, means guard bit is useful in this case.

In these two cases, we have different rounding bit, so may get different results.
Which case we should follow?
I couldn't see any document/paper talks about this topic clearly.

Comment: _This is a very simple question, but needs expert to answer_: this is sort of not the definition of a _simple_ question,

Comment: If you were to specify either the computations in question, or their results in real number arithmetic, it would be easy to tell you which way each result should be rounded.

Comment: Also, there will inevitably be a gap, containing an infinity of real numbers, between 0 and the smallest positive float. The use of subnormal numbers makes that gap no bigger than the gap between the smallest and next-to-smallest positive floats.

Comment: Thanks  @kvantour for revising the code.

Comment: I am still unclear about what calculation is being rounded. Perhaps make it more concrete by picking e.g. 64-bit.

Comment: Note: `(0.1111...1|r)*2^emin` and `(1.1111...1|r')*2^(emin-1)` are different values.  The later has more `1`s in it.

Comment: suppose we have two numbers with finite precision (but larger than the format we need), say

`n1 = (0.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1100)*2^(-126)`


`n2 = (0.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1000)*2^(-126)`

if exp is unbounded, `n1` is on the middle of two finite precision numbers, but `n2` is on the middle of two representable numbers of ieee754 flp32 format.

Comment: @Patrick In each case, does the real number you are rounding have any 1 bits of lower significance than the bits you are showing?

Comment: Both `n1` and `n2` should round up, to the smallest normal number. `n1` is closer to it. `n2` is half way between it and the largest subnormal, and rounds up because the larger of those numbers is even.

Comment: No other bits with lower significance. Our c model rounds up only `n1` to minimum normal, and keep `n2` as the largest subnormal.@PatriciaShanahan

Comment: These two numbers are corner cases, so we make it just on the possible half way.

Answer (score 7):

IEEE 754 rounding is not specified in terms of rounding bits or guard digits. It is specified in terms of the [real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) the computation would have produced if we could do our math in exact, real-number arithmetic instead of limited-precision floating point.

When the exact value of a computation is exactly halfway between two representable numbers, round-half-to-even rounds to the option whose representation in the current floating-point format would have an even least-significant mantissa digit. This can also be thought of as rounding to the option that would have a higher power of two if both options were written as an odd integer times a power of two (and treating 0 as having a higher power of two than other numbers).

Guard digits may be involved in an implementation, as long as the implementation produces the specified rounding behavior. IEEE 754 does not mandate any particular rounding implementation, only the behavior of the various rounding modes.

Comment: +1 The first paragraph is particularly important. I can normally understand and explain IEEE 754 rounding, but am having trouble understanding the question here. I think my problem is that the question uses an implementation based model of rounding, not the much simpler and clearer specification.

Comment: I think the question is asking if the **implementation** is correct, or how it can/should be implemented. The spec telling you that it should be as close to the real mathematical value as possible doesn't help a lot there. I think the question is not "what to do?" but "how to do that?".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: The question reads to me like it doesn't understand the criteria by which an implementation would be considered correct.

Comment: @user2357112: yes, because OP does not know how this can be checked/tested. Comes down to the same question: how do I know what is correct **in code**?

Comment: Right, actually I'm an IC engineer and is working on the floating-point circuit implementation. The question is really rare in real application, and is not very easy to be verified. The simplest and most "golden" method is to use fma instruction provided directly by some ISAs, and also it has to support denormal mode. We have a c model, but the behavior of the c model cannot pursuade me. So I'm trying to get confirm from anybody who has this experience (maybe who has worked on software lib or hardware impl.)  Thanks for all the feedback~~

Comment: If IEEE754 is trying the best to make a finite precision computation close to (or mimic) it's infinite real number counterpart, the **case 2** looks more reasonable. It causes one ugly thing, that is "the half point is no longer in the right middle of two **representable** numbers".

Comment: @Patrick If the real number result falls between two finite representable numbers, round-half-even always rounds to whichever is closer. If the real number is exactly half way between them, it rounds to even. If an algorithm makes the cutoff anywhere other than half way between the two representable numbers, it is not IEEE 754.

Comment: hmmm, this explanation sounds reasonable, let me give an example in the above comments@PatriciaShanahan

Answer (score 0):

The OP needs practical ways to test results. Java has several useful properties. Its rounding, in `strictfp` mode, matches the IEEE754 standard, so it can serve as a reference implementation. This program illustrates rounding of the number exactly half way between the 32 bit minimum positive normal and largest subnormal numbers.

```
public strictfp class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printIt(Float.MIN_NORMAL);
    printIt(Math.nextDown(Float.MIN_NORMAL));
    double d = ((double)Float.MIN_NORMAL + (double)Math.nextDown(Float.MIN_NORMAL))/2;
    printIt((float)d);
  }
  static void printIt(float f){
    int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(bits);
    while(s.length() < 32){
      s = "0" + s;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
00000000100000000000000000000000
00000000011111111111111111111111
00000000100000000000000000000000
```

In a comment, the OP asked for analysis of the following cases:

```
n1=Math.nextDown(Float.MIN_NORMAL) + Float.MIN_NORMAL*(2^-24) + Float.MIN_NORMAL*(2^-25) 

n2=Math.nextDown(Float.MIN_NORMAL) + Float.MIN_NORMAL*(2^-24)
```

I am assuming the intermediate calculations should be done in real number, not `float`, arithmetic.

According to my calculations, the real number values are:

```
n1=0.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1011_1111_1111_1111_1111_1110_1 * MIN_NORMAL
n2=0.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111 * MIN_NORMAL
```

The mid-point between `MIN_NORMAL` and the maximum subnormal is:

```
0.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1 * MIN_NORMAL
```

`n1` is greater than the mid-point, and therefore must round up to `MIN_NORMAL`. `n2` is less than the mid-point, and therefore must round down to the largest subnormal. Those are the results I get from Java.

Comment: Addition may not be able to show the case, if it's convenient for you, please try this:
`n1=Math.nextDown(Float.MIN_NORMAL) + Float.MIN_NORMAL*(2^-24) + Float.MIN_NORMAL*(2^-25)`

`n2=Math.nextDown(Float.MIN_NORMAL) + Float.MIN_NORMAL*(2^-24)`

I dont have Java env, I will check if can get any thing similar in Python.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Patrick I have added analysis of your examples to my answer.

Comment: So looks Java and Python have the same behavior. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I found this (since I'm not python expert, so I'm not sure if this is golden enough):

```
import numpy as np
import struct
def float_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', f))[0])
if __name__=='__main__':
    min_normal = np.float64(1*(2**-126))
    max_denorm = np.float64(1*(2**-126)-1*(2**-126)*(2**-23))
    # Emin(-126) * (0.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111)_11
    n1 = np.float32(max_denorm+min_normal*np.float64(2**-24)+min_normal*np.float64(2**-25))
    # Emin(-126) * (0.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111)_10
    n2 = np.float32(max_denorm+min_normal*np.float64(2**-24))
    # Emin(-126) * (0.111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111)_01
    n3 = np.float32(max_denorm+min_normal*np.float64(2**-25))

    print(float_to_hex(n1))
    print(float_to_hex(n2))
    print(float_to_hex(n3))
```

`python2 on x86_64 linux` output is:

`0x800000
0x800000
0x7fffff`

looks python2 follows round_half_to_even by default, and pick up the bit after 24 bits significand as the rounding bit.

This is what I found so far, maybe Python or arithmetic experts can give some feedbacks.

Ps. This feedback is too long for a comment, so I put it here@PatriciaShanahan .

Thanks Patricia

Comment: The behavior is not the same as our c model... this is the issue what I'm facing.

Comment: Looks Python and Java have the same feedback. The half way between max_denorm and min_normal is the **first case** in the question

Comment: I would expect the second case to round up, because it is exactly half way between two representable numbers and the greater one is even. The other two cases are simple round-to-nearest. However, you need to consider all bits of the real result, not just the first bit or two that are being dropped. If the real result is greater than the mid-point by even one part a billion, you need to round up even if the greater value is odd.

Comment: I suggest looking at cases where the greater bracketing value is odd. That way you can probe whether the implementation is correctly distinguishing values even slightly greater than the mid-point from the exact mid-point.

Comment: I suggest testing round to 32 bit float on the following two doubles: `1.000000059604644775390625` and `1.00000005960464566356904470012523233890533447265625`. The first one is exactly half way between 1.0f and Math.nextUp(1.0f), and should round down because 1.0f is even. The second is a little bit bigger, and should round up.

Comment: If the C model is getting a different answer from the Python results you show above, you need to either correct or scrap the C model.

Comment: `1.000000059604644775390625` and `1.0000000596046456635690447001252323389053344726562` cannot show the case, since they are in the normal number range, I know exactly what they should be in the flp32 format. And I cannot update c model, since we have many massive products based on it, and I cannot quote my company's name, but anybody here knows it...... I will  check more about this topic in Python for making the conclusion solid enough. hmmm, this is what I can do. Thanks @PatriciaShanahan

Comment: In that case, given you are doing work where the IEEE 754 rounding rules are critical, you should have your employer purchase a copy of the standard and keep it on your desk. I did when I was working, but I retired before the latest standard came out in 2008, so I only have the 1985 version.

Comment: At least in ANSI/IEEE Std 754-1985, round-to-nearest has no special rule for the normal/subnormal boundary: "In this mode the representable value nearest to the infinitely precise result shall be delivered;...", and goes on to the tiebreaker rule and how to decide to round to infinity.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan This is what I'm concerning, no rule, and we may get slight difference on results between different platforms...software lib maybe is ok on this with special announcement in manual, but if we have difference in hardware ISAs, this maybe a problem. Actually I'm expecting a comparison between Intel, AMD and maybe NV